# Finding off integers

Tags: c

I'm trying to get this code to give an error whenever someone inputs a negative or even integer. I have the negative integer but I can't seem to find a way to get the system to give an error message when an even integer is inputted.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int size, i, j, spaces, stars, true, false;


    printf("How many rows do you want?\n"); //ask the user how many rows they want
    scanf("%d", &size);

    //this check to make sure a positive, odd integer is entered
    if(size <= 0)
        printf("sorry, but you need to input a positive, odd integer.\n");


    int mid = size/2 +1; //this is to find the midpoint of the diamond where you will start decrementing

    //menu options


    //this is the for loop that will create your rows
    for(i = 1; i <= size; i++){
            if(i < mid){
                spaces = mid - i;
                stars = size - (spaces*2);
            }
            if(i > mid){
                spaces = i - mid;
                stars = size - (spaces*2);
            }
            if (i == mid){
                spaces = 0;
                stars = size;
            }

        for(j = 0; j < spaces; j++)
            printf(" ");
        for(j = 0; j < stars; j++)
            printf("*");

        printf("\n");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't the question you're asking, but you might want a return statement after your error check... as it is, it will print an error message and then keep right on going.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(size % 2 == 0)
    printf("sorry, even integer not allowed.\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//this check to make sure a positive, odd integer is entered
if(size <= 0 || size%2==0)
    printf("sorry, but you need to input a positive, odd integer.\n");
```

Edit: if you want to stop executing after this error - simply use `return`:

```
//this check to make sure a positive, odd integer is entered
if(size <= 0 || size%2==0)
{
    printf("sorry, but you need to input a positive, odd integer.\n");
    return 1; // A return value different than 0 usually indicates an error
}
```

Comment: But the program continues to run if something that doesn't fit those parameters is entered. SHould I have this in a loop?

Comment: Wow thank you I don't know that about return values. Thank you!